# Gravitational force on two/three objects

Tags: forces, gravity, experimental-physics, acceleration, time

I've just seen the part of the BBC documentary *Human Universe* titled ["Brian Cox visits the world's biggest vacuum chamber" (Episode 4)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E43-CfukEgs), made in cooperation with NASA in the biggest vacuum chamber in the world.

They made an experiment to prove that a bowling ball (~3 kg) will "came down exactly the same" as a bunch of feathers (I would say ~0.1 kg).

I think this is not true, probably due to Newton's law of universal gravitation.

I would like to know what is the time difference between those two objects hitting the ground. The height is 20 meters.

It would be also great to include the force of gravitation of all of the 3 objects in the experiment, because I think that a gravitational force of a bowling ball and the feathers will make the trajectories elliptic.

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE. I would ask why you can't do the calculation yourself, based on sites such as hyperphysics.com. **I think this is not true, probably due to Newton's law of universal gravitation**  I can only speak for myself, but I think this is not what you meant to say, or if it is, I don't follow what your point is. Sorry.

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to do the calculations and the site you provided - hyperphysics.com - is a domain for sale and I can't see any helpful resources on there. And your citation of my words is exactly what I wanted to say. Thank you!

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hph.html

Comment: What specifically do you think is not true?

Answer (score 1):

A problem with that documentary is that the fall in vacuum is shown in slow  motion only, without any notification. This is not obvious to all laymen, as some associate vacuum with reduced gravity.

But yes, within experimental error, the feather will have the same acceleration as the ball: 9.8 m/s$^2$.